# Is there any way to retrive children doc with the query on parent document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent doc u1 contain {userId:1} with routing u1r1 and 
I have    3 children related to this doc u1 ie o1u1,o2u1,o3u1.

```
o1u1 contain {city:a},
o2u1 contain {city:b},
o3u1 contain {city:a}
```

I want both userId with two document contain {city:a}.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inner_hits` if you want child documents along with parent documents.

```
{
"query": {
  "has_child": {
     "type": "child",
     "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "city",
           "query": "a"
        }
     },
     "inner_hits": {}
     }
   }
}
```

Study about `inner_hits` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)